# javax validation @min ignore 0

Tags: java, validation, jackson

I'd like to know how to make `@min` validation to ignore 0, because Jackson deserialize all null value to int 0, and I want to ignore the null value.

```
public class A{
   private String name;
   @Min(1)
   private int number;
}
```

For example I send a JSON `{"name": "xxx"}`, it will cause validation error since jackson automatically map number null to 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can map "number" a `Integer` instead of int. That way, "number" will be mapped to null instead of an "1".